# Add pagination to listing plugin

Tags: widgets, pagination, plugin-list-category-post

I am trying to figure out on how to add pagination to your listing.
Think you could help me out?

I have added the read more button and manage to customise the listing styles.
What's left is the pagination. If its achievable, it did be one of the best plugins available.

And how do I use the custom fields? I don't quite get what you mean in the instructions. I am planning to add more fields so I can add in phone number and so on.

Your plugin has the potential of being a directory listing plugin that is customisable. Love it.

Answer (score 1):

Pagination has been on the TODO list for a while, but I haven't had time to get to implement it yet. I would be glad to receive some code from the community on this one :)

The only complexity I can think of right now is there can be more than one instance of the shortcode, so each one should have an id to pass via GET for the pagination parameters.